# Do I need to patch my tubed-tire if I have a puncture?

Tags: tire, puncture

I have about a 2 mm gash around the outside of my tire from a piece of brown glass. It gave me a slow leak and while I've patched the tube, do I need to do anything about the tire itself?

[image: Punctured tube]

Comment: One can't tell from the photo whether the cord under the tread has been substantially damaged.  This would be more obvious looking on the inside.  If the cord is damaged (more than just a nail-sized area) then you need to "boot" the tire or replace it.

Answer (score 6):

I think thats small enough that I probably wouldn't worry about it too much, but you can fill it in with a dab of super glue or sealants for rubber (like shoe goo) for peace of mind.

You could boot it (a nice boot is the Park Tool TB-2), but I think this is likely too much work.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If the threads on the inside of the tyre are not damaged, only check for any left-over glass debris in the gash and leave as-is.

Otherwise, either ditch the tyre or boot it from the inside, like @Batman suggested already.

Comment: The next time I get a flat I'll take a picture of the inside. From what I remember, there wasn't significant damage on the inner surface, but didn't pay it much mind. I actually did 'boot' it (didn't know what that was) with a small square of 3M rubber splice tape because it seemed like maybe a good idea (question was later in the day after I patched my tube)